# Jsp doesn't connect to the servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, url-pattern

I'm getting the error 404 not found When I'm trying to call a new Servlet.

I've already set up the urlPatterns at the servlet and I'm linking the JSP file correctly, I think. Look below the archives.

Servlet:

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import dao.DAOFactory;
import dao.DiagnosisDAO;
import model.Category;
import model.Diagnosis;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DiagnosisController
 */
@MultipartConfig
@WebServlet(name = "/DiagnosisController", urlPatterns = {
        "/diagnosis",
        "/diagnosis/all"
})

public class DiagnosisController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DiagnosisController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher;


        switch(request.getServletPath()) {
        case "/diagnosis":
            DiagnosisDAO diagDao;
            try(DAOFactory daoFactory = new DAOFactory()){
                diagDao = daoFactory.getDiagnosisDAO();

                Diagnosis diag = diagDao.get_DMFSteam();
                request.setAttribute("DSteam", diag.getDMFSteamList());

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("error", e1.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("error", e1.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("error", e1.getMessage());
            }
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/diagnosis/charts.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            break;
        }
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And this is the JSP:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : navbar
    Created on : 03/07/2018, 11:55:04
    Author     : dskaster
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <span class="navbar-brand"><a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/view/menuInicial.jsp">Banco de Dados</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/view/menuInicial.jsp">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Jogos<span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/game">Listar jogos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/game/create/first">Cadastrar jogo</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/developer">Desenvolvedoras</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/publisher">Publicadoras</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/view/category/create.jsp">Nova Categoria</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/view/json/import.jsp">Upload Json</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/diagnosis/all">Diagnósticos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The last "li" of the JSP file is "*href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/diagnosis/all*", that should call the Servlet above, but doesn't work. I've already tried to create a new Controller but still doesn't work.

I really need help with this issue, It has been a lot of time with this error and I'm giving up of this project.

I'm using the Eclipse IDE Photon with apache tomcat 8.0 and 9.0.

Comment: Try only `"href="/diagnosis/all"`

Comment: Did you try with `@WebServlet("/diagnosis/all")` ?

Comment: I've tried both, but none worked. It may be a Tomcat problem?

Comment: No repo. Works well in Tomcat 8.0.27

Comment: debug at line switch, try to print something to make sure expression language is working, can you provide project structure as screen shot may be

Comment: I found the error, that was at the Servlet, in "@MultipartConfig". I've removed it, and works. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, that was at the Servlet, I've removed the tag "@MultipartConfig", and all works. The Servlet is like that:

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import dao.DAOFactory;
import dao.DiagnosisDAO;
import model.Category;
import model.Diagnosis;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DiagnosisController
 */

@WebServlet(name = "/DiagnosisController", urlPatterns = {
        "/diagnosis",
        "/diagnosis/all"
})

public class DiagnosisController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DiagnosisController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher;


        switch(request.getServletPath()) {
        case "/diagnosis":
            DiagnosisDAO diagDao;
            try(DAOFactory daoFactory = new DAOFactory()){
                diagDao = daoFactory.getDiagnosisDAO();

                Diagnosis diag = diagDao.get_DMFSteam();
                request.setAttribute("DSteam", diag.getDMFSteamList());

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("error", e1.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("error", e1.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("error", e1.getMessage());
            }
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/diagnosis/charts.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            break;
        }
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Thank you guys.